# WCF Server Error. The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding

Tags: wcf

I've got a WCF Service, which calls a webservice, running on my development IIS server (IIS 7). I've added it as a service reference to a C# Website Project and it adds fine.

However, when I try to call any of the service contracts, I get the following error:

> The content type text/html
>   of the response message does not match
>   the content type of the binding
>   (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a
>   custom encoder, be sure that the
>   IsContentTypeSupported method is
>   implemented properly. The first 1024
>   bytes of the response were:
>   'Blocked Web
>   Page

thanks in advance

BB

Answer (score 4):

The error message says it clearly: you're getting back an HTML page instead of your service response. Looking at the fragment of that page listed in the error message, you're probably not authroized to use that service.

Try to connect to the service URL in a browser - you should probably see a page explaining that you're not allowed to access the page. Most likely, this is a permissions issue.

Comment: @ marc_s thank you. I am able to connect to the service in a browser.

Comment: @BumbleBee > If you think that this question is answered then please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [configure WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) and find out what's happening on the server side.